# R Selenium click image button

Tags: r, selenium

I am trying to click GO button which is gif image in the following url.

http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/histstock.php

I am using R Selenium in Mac.

I tried using findElement but was not able to find any element for this image button.

I tried using mouseMoveToLocation but am not able to find the right x, y coordinates to click on this button.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using Chrome for such search. Using so just:

RMB on the element you want->inspect element->RMB on test highlighted->copy->copy Xpath.

That was there is no chance that you will "miss" element with wrong click, every button has it's own Xpath

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did go to the element as I have identified it earlier.  <input type="image" src="http://img1.moneycontrol.com/images/histstock/go_btn.gif" alt="" align="top">.   However, it is an image and not able to click on the image using R Selenium.

Comment: Ok, didn't use Rselenium on Mac, though Xpath extracted using any browser on any system is the same, and may work (not sure though).
If you can't I may paste these 3 xpaths:
1. Daily: //*[@id="mc_mainWrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/div[4]/input[1]
2. Monthly: //*[@id="mc_mainWrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/form/div[4]/input[1]
3. Yearly: //*[@id="mc_mainWrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div[2]/form/input[1]

Comment: Thank you @Myszsoda. It worked. I now understand how did you get the Xpaths for the elements in question.